# jquery rewrite after jQuery.noConflict();

Tags: javascript, jquery

I run this JS on page,

but if I clear js with `jQuery.noConflict();` it will not work.

I checked JS console, but no luck, because this is working only when hover over image.

### Q:

What `jQuery.noConflict();` does to this code that it will not work ?

### My thoughts how to fix it:

That `$` must be replaced with propper `jQuery`, but I am not very good with jQuery, and don't know, which `$` must be replaced. If so, **which `$` should I replace** in code?

example:

```
// Start
        $.mglass = function(element, options) {
```

replace with

```
// Start
        jQuery.mglass = function(element, options) {
```

Thank you for your answers, corrections and code.

### JS:

What this JS does, it displays a magnifying glass on image hover

source: https://github.com/younes0/jQuery-MGlass

```
jquery library code here ...

jQuery.noConflict();

(function($) {

    // Start
    $.mglass = function(element, options) {

        // Defaults
        var defaults = {
            opacity: 0.4,
            speed: 150,
            wrapper: true
        };

        var plugin = this, $element = $(element);

        plugin.settings = {};


        // Constructor
        plugin.init = function() {

            plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

            if (plugin.settings.wrapper) {
                $element.wrap('<div class="mglassWrapper" />');
            }

            var 
                h = $element.height(), 
                w = $element.width(),
                b = $element.css('border-top-width')
            ;

            var overlayStyle = 'width: '+w+'px; height: '+h+'px;'; 

            // if original image has border (border-top as reference), set width as margin
            if (b) {
                overlayStyle+= 'margin: '+b+';';
            }

            // CSS3 transition Support ?
            if (typeof $.css3Transitions === 'undefined') {
                $.css3Transitions = plugin.supportsTransitions();
            }
            if ($.css3Transitions) {
                overlayStyle+= $.fn.mglass.transitionProperty+': opacity '+(plugin.settings.speed/1000)+'s ease;';
            }

            // Mglass Div
            $overlay = $('<div class="mglass" style="'+overlayStyle+'"></div>');
            $overlay.insertBefore($(element));

            // No CSS3 transition support : javascript fallback
            if ( ! $.css3Transitions) {
                $overlay.hover(
                    function () {
                        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": plugin.settings.opacity}, plugin.settings.speed);
                    },
                    function () {
                        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 0}, 100);
                    }
                );
            }


        },

        plugin.supportsTransitions = function() {

            var el      = document.createElement('div');
            var vendors = ['', 'Ms', 'Moz', 'Webkit', 'O'];

            for (var i = 0, len = vendors.length; i < len; i++) {
                var prop = vendors[i] + 'Transition';
                if (prop in el.style) {
                    $.fn.mglass.transitionProperty = '-'+vendors[i].toLowerCase()+'-transition';
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;

        };


        // Init
        plugin.init();

    };

    // Add the plugin to the jQuery.fn object
    $.fn.mglass = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (undefined === $(this).data('mglass')) {
                var plugin = new $.mglass(this, options);
                $(this).data('mglass', plugin);
            }
        });
    };

// End
})(jQuery);
```

Then in HTML I post this in end of content of page

```
<script>
   jQuery("img").mglass({
       opacity: 0.5
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the `jQuery.noConflict();`? if it is outside of that code, it shouldn't affect it,

Comment: I'm not seeing something wrong with the script. It correctly wraps the `$` as `jQuery` object. There's probably something wrong with your code that calls this! You can post that here too...

Comment: Do you actually need to use `jQuery.noConflict();` ?
The only reason you would want to use it, is to prevent ambiguity between jQuery's `$` and (possibly) another library's `$`, like the one from prototype.js

Comment: yes I need to clear that, because I use another libraries in some parts of page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is in edited code, I added `(function($) { }` in-front of code, so that `$` is operational, and is not crossing other libraries

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it seems like the plugin is "functioning" although it may not be getting the results that you want.

See the code in the bottom this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxvDq/1/)** (Moo tools is on the page to provide the conflict over `$`). I've added a simple fade  to the element that  $.mglass acts on, and called the plugin on an image on the page. The `fadeto` triggers, and the `.mglass` wrapper div that the plugin creates is being added to the DOM.

One initial thought on why this is not working is CSS, have you added the `mglass` css to your page?

Comment: solution is in edited code, I added `(function($) { }` in-front of code, so that `$` is operational, and is not crossing other libraries

Answer (score 0):

If anything, no rewrite is necessary if you do this:

```
(function ($) {
    // your old code here
}(jQuery.noConflict()));
```